# Magento2 how to get options values for drop down filed at checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, drop-downs

i have followed this reference link https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form it is working fine for input fields saving.

1) I would like to display custom drop down field with the options (dynamically) at checkout page, in the layout file **checkout_index_index.xml** i have hard coded drop down values now. if want to achieve **dynamically** how to do?

> checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/js/view/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="checkout_buyer_name" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>                                                                                        
                                                                                    </item>
                                                          <!-- Added for drop down values hard coded-->                          
                                                          <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please select value</item>
                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string"></item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 1</item>
                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_1</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 2</item>
                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <!-- Added for drop down values hard coded -->         
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_buyer_name</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Buyer name</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                                </item>

                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Instead of static how to do dynamic?

Comment: Looks like Knockout.js job.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin for the checkout LayoutProcessor to dynamically populate the options for that dropdown.

### 1. Declare the Plugin

**app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="your_checkout_layout_processor" type="YourNamespace\YourModeul\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

### 2. Create the "afterProcess" Plugin

#### Simplified Hardcoded Version

**app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/Plugin/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php**

```php
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * Checkout LayoutProcessor after process plugin.
     *
     * @param LayoutProcessor $processor
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $processor, array $jsLayout): array
    {
        $yourSelect = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
        ['custom-checkout-form-container']['children']['custom-checkout-form-fieldset']['children']
        ['checkout_buyer_name'];

        if (isset($yourSelect)) {
            $yourSelect['options'] = $this->getYourOptions();
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Get referral options
     *
     * @return array
     * @todo inject the classes you need in the construct and call it here
     */
    protected function getYourOptions()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value' => '',
                'label' => __('-- Please Select --')
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'value_1',
                'label' => __('Value 1')
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'value_2',
                'label' => __('Value 2')
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

The above is basically the same as what you wrote in the XML for the `options`.  I kept the values hardcoded for now to keep it simple.  However, now that we are in the PHP we can inject a model and dynamically populate the options by adding the `__construct()` and updating the method with the array...

#### Dynamic Version

```php
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $regionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->regionCollectionFactory = $regionCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Checkout LayoutProcessor after process plugin.
     *
     * @param LayoutProcessor $processor
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $processor, array $jsLayout): array
    {
        $yourSelect = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
        ['custom-checkout-form-container']['children']['custom-checkout-form-fieldset']['children']
        ['checkout_buyer_name'];

        if (isset($yourSelect)) {
            $yourSelect['options'] = $this->getYourOptions();
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Get referral options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getYourOptions()
    {
        $regionOptions = [
            [
                'value' => '',
                'label' => __('-- Please Select --')
            ]
        ];
        $regionsCollection = $this->regionCollectionFactory->create()->load();
        $regionsCollection->addFieldToFilter('country_id', 'US');
        $regionData = $regionsCollection->getData();
        foreach ($regionData as $region) {
            $regionOptions[] = [
                'value' => $region['region_id'],
                'label' =>  $region['default_name']
            ];
        }
        return $regionOptions;
    }
}
```